# Why is readtext::readtext() returning a list instead of data.frame?

Tags: r, json, dataframe

I am reading a json file using the [readtext package](https://rdrr.io/github/quanteda/readtext/man/readtext.html), the documentation mentions the return value as `data.frame` (see excerpt from the documentation below), however I am getting back a `list` instead.

> Value: a data.frame consisting of a columns doc_id and text that contain a document identifier and the texts respectively, with any additional columns consisting of document-level variables either found in the file containing the texts, or created through the readtext call.

In addition I also get the following on console, in response to `readtext()`

> File doesn't contain a single valid JSON object.

here is my call to the function

```
data <- readtext(file = "./bytecup.corpus.train.0.json",
                 text_field = c("content", "id", "title")) 
typeof(data)
[1] "list"
str(data)
'data.frame':  n obs. of m variables
```

All the data is correctly populated in the list. I know i can convert the 'list' to 'data.frame' but that's not what I am looking for.

**Question:** how to get a `data.frame` without having to convert from a `list`

**Update:** [link to sample json file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zTsi71ABpY7y8WOcIOIL0qz5p1ch8mx9/view?usp=sharing)

I have added the output of `typeof()` and `str()`, I think it would be useful to answer the question.

Comment: Sharing `bytecup.corpus.train.0.json` would be helpful.

Comment: `bytecup.corpus.train.0.json` is quite large I am sharing link to `mnw.json` containing first two records of the original file

Comment: After writing my answer (now deleted) I realized that while it does fix `File doesn't contain a single valid JSON object.`, I cannot reproduce your issue regarding a list. Do you also have the same problem with your sample file?

Comment: I fixed the `File doesn't contain a single valid JSON object.` Taking help of [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/). Multiple JSON objects need to be enclosed in square brackets separated by commas i.e. `[ {obj1}, {obj2}]`. The `list` issue still exists.

Comment: Right, my answer about `File doesn't contain a single valid JSON object.` was the same. But do you have this `list` issue also with the sample JSON file?

Comment: Yes I have the list issue with sample JSON file.

Comment: Now I'm looking at your update and cannot understand what the issue even is. `'data.frame':  n obs. of m variables` as an output to `str(data)` is what you want. Getting a list to `typeof(data.frame(a = 1:3))` *is* what you should expect because data frame *is* a special kind of a list.